# Crystal Report shows data multiple times

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am facing a problem where I get data in a report 4 times because I fill the data adaptor 4 times

Here is my code:

```
MyCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
myDA.SelectCommand = MyCommand;
myDA.Fill(myDS, "Stock");
myDA.Fill(myDS, "Stock_Product");
myDA.Fill(myDS, "Product");
myDA.Fill(myDS, "Supplier");

rd.Load(@"C:\Users\aliali\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\GenesysInventory System\GenesysInventory System\rptpurchase.rpt");
rd.SetDataSource(myDS);

frmReport obj = new frmReport();
obj.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
obj.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Why do you need to call myDA.Fill() 4 times? surely you mean to fill 4 tables, then add the tables to the dataset?

Comment: please give an example fotr ref,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workflow is to create tables, fill your tables, then add them to the dataset, then set the dataset as your report datasource.

```
var dtStock = new DataTable("Stock");
MyCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
myDA.SelectCommand = MyCommand;
myDA.Fill(dtStock, "Stock");
// another command for Stock_Product
var dtStockProduct =new DataTable("Stock_Product");
stockProductDA.SelectCommand = StockProductCommand;
stockProductDA.Fill(dtStockProduct, "Stock_Product");
// fill all the tables

// finally, add all the tables to your data set
myDS.Tables.Add(dtStock);
myDS.Tables.Add(dtStockProduct);
// continue as normal
rd.Load(@"C:\Users\aliali\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\GenesysInventory System\GenesysInventory System\rptpurchase.rpt");
rd.SetDataSource(myDS);

frmReport obj = new frmReport();
obj.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
obj.ShowDialog();
```